# Changing one EditText in ListView changes all

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

I know there are similar questions like this and I've been following a lot of code posted on here to get to this point, but none of them work to my adapter. I've also *not* used `ViewHolders` like many other people do as I do not really understand what they are for.

In my adapter class I wanted editing an `editText` to change its corresponding value in my `ArrayList` of event objects. However now changing one's event `EditText` field changes them all, even though I use `mobileArrayList.get(position)`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

ArrayList<Event> mobileArrayList;


public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Event> events){
    super(context, 0, events);
    this.mobileArrayList = events;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Event event = mobileArrayList.get(position);
    //ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        //holder = new ViewHolder();
       // holder.caption = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events);
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        //holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    EditText events = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events);
    EditText start = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    EditText end = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end);
    TextView day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);

    events.setText(event.getSummary());
    start.setText("Start Date: " +event.getDateStart());
    end.setText("End Date: " + event.getDateEnd());
    day.setText(event.getDayOfTheWeek());

    /*holder.caption.setId(position);

    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText events = (EditText) v;
                mobileArrayList.get(position).setSummary(events.getText().toString());

            }
        }
    });*/

    events.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String edit = s.toString();
            mobileArrayList.get(position).setSummary(edit);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    EditText caption;
}

}
```

I should also note once I get this working for the events `EditText` field I will also be doing the same for the other two. Thank you

EDIT: If I try to use this with ViewHolders instead, it throws an NPE when I try to assign the first `holder.events = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events)`. Here is the code using ViewHolders:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

ArrayList<Event> mobileArrayList;


public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Event> events){
    super(context, 0, events);
    this.mobileArrayList = events;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Event event = mobileArrayList.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    /*EditText events = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events);
    EditText start = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    EditText end = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end);
    TextView day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
    */

    holder.events = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events);
    holder.start = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    holder.end = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end);
    holder.day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);

    holder.events.setText(event.getSummary());
    holder.start.setText("Start Date: " +event.getDateStart());
    holder.end.setText("End Date: " + event.getDateEnd());
    holder.day.setText(event.getDayOfTheWeek());

    /*holder.caption.setId(position);

    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText events = (EditText) v;
                mobileArrayList.get(position).setSummary(events.getText().toString());

            }
        }
    });*/

    holder.events.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String edit = s.toString();
            mobileArrayList.get(position).setSummary(edit);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    EditText events;
    EditText start;
    EditText end;
    TextView day;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to use View Holder concept for it , or better go for recycler view

Comment: where did u  you use notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @CharukaSilva I haven't here, I can post my main activity if that helps. It seems to change the value displayed here without it

Comment: try removing  if(convertView == null) condition and add notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @Redman I'm having the same issue I was having earlier with using a viewholder. For some reason it can initialize my EditText events, start, day, and end values just fine, but when I try to intiialize it as part of a holder it throws an NPE. I am editing my question to show what I mean

Comment: @Nithin where will the notifyDataSetChanged() go? At the end of public void afterTextChanged?

Comment: you have to notify in afterTextChnaged Method.

Comment: log/ print your position inside the getView and see the value

Comment: @Nithin it worked! I forgot to remove the if(convertView == null) at first but adding the notifyDataSetChanged() only edits the `editText` I want it to! Only problem is that now after make one edit, like adding or deleting a single letter, it snaps out of the the text field, but that is a much more manageable problem. Thank you

Comment: I'm having the same issue johnny with the snapping out of the text field. Did you ever get around that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try removing `if(convertView == null)` condition.